# cakePHP custom textarea input fields (WYSIWYG)

Tags: cakephp, tinymce, ckeditor, cakephp-2.0

I'm new in cakePHP and I need to have a custom input field in my blog post.

I explored:

ckeditor - problematic in file uploading from directory.
 
TinyMCE - Having problem in integrating new version to cakePHP 2.3.8.

Can someone direct me to some up-to-date sample of these editors? or any guide how to make my own custom editor. Or any suggestions what other alternatives I can use?

Comment: Not sure if I understood what you want... A WYSIWYG editor in CakePHP? Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's waht i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I hope I got that right: you need a WYSIWYG editor on your CakePHP blog.
You do not want to use ckeditor as you are experiencing file uploading problems.
After a quick search fpr "wysiwyg cakephp" I found several links, including a "setup guide":

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/galitul/2012/04/11/helper_tinymce_for_cakephp_2

More on tinymce helpers...

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/daibach/2008/07/15/tinymce-helper-1

Another link collection:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles?by=tinymce

if you are looking for another WYSIWYG editor try the following link list:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles?by=wysiwyg

Or this editor:

https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-wysiwyg-helper

Hope that helps...